# Set params in httpInterceptor is overriding extra params I want to append

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

Current Behaviour:
I have created an HttpInterceptor that sets an id and token to all requests if the users credentials are available to get. When I try to set an extra HttpParam in a request it gets overwritten by the interceptor.

Expected Behaviour:
Would like to be able to set extra parameters if needed and have the interceptor append the default id and token.

I get why the behaviour is so but is there a workaround to have the interceptor set the http params and append any extra request params?

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpParams,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { exhaustMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.authService.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      exhaustMap((user) => {
        // For requests that do not need authentication, it will proceed without attaching params. E.g Login.
        if (!user) {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
        const modifiedReq = req.clone({
          params: new HttpParams()
            .set('id', user.id)
            .set('token', user.token),
        });
        return next.handle(modifiedReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
  fetchCompaniesByUserId() {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(
        `${environment.apiUrl}/GetCompaniesByUserId`,
        {
          params: new HttpParams().set('timestamp', Date.now().toString()),
        }
      ).subscribe()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but you could try to append to the existing parameters in `req`.

```js
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.authService.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      exhaustMap((user) => {
        // For requests that do not need authentication, it will proceed without attaching params. E.g Login.
        if (!user) {
          return next.handle(req);
        }
        const modifiedReq = req.clone({
          params: req.params             // <-- append to existing `params` in `req`
            .set('id', user.id)
            .set('token', user.token),
        });
        return next.handle(modifiedReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```